# Apache Reverse Proxy: Limit POST / PUT but allow unatuthenticated GET / HEAD

Tags: docker, apache, reverse-proxy, docker-registry, apache-config

I am running a [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) behind an Apache Reverse Proxy that provides:

- SSL Termination
- Basic Auth for `GET` / `HEAD`
- Basic Auth for `POST` / `PUT` / `PATCH` / `DELETE`

based on the reference example for [Authenticate proxy with Apache](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/apache/) by Docker.

I would like to remove the Authentication requirement for `GET` & `HEAD`, and allow unauthenticated users to read / `pull` from the registry. However, I'm unable to.

```
<Location /v2>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  AuthName "Registry Authentication"
  AuthType basic
  AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.htpasswd"
  AuthGroupFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.groups"

  # Read access to authentified users
  <Limit GET HEAD>
    Require valid-user
  </Limit>

  # Write access to docker-deployer only
  <Limit POST PUT DELETE PATCH>
    Require group pusher
  </Limit>

</Location>
```

I tried to:

- remove the `<Limit GET HEAD>` section;
- add `Require all granted` instead of `Require valid-user`;
- replace with `LimitExcept`;
- replace with `RequireAny` as per the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#reqmethod).

but I have not been able to figure out the correct syntax. If unauthenticated `GET` works, `POST` causes: `unauthorized: authentication required`

I would like to:

- restrict `push`ing to the registry (`POST`/`PUT`/`PATCH`) to authenticated users & groups;
- but allow unauthenticated `pull`ing (`GET`/`HEAD`).

Comment: Have you tried to move the auth* directives to the <Limit> block?

Comment: Thanks @SergioSantiago. Would you kindly post an example, and I'll try it out?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move the auth directives to the Require block?

```
<Location /v2>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    # Read access to authentified users
    <Limit GET HEAD>
        Require all granted
    </Limit>

    # Write access to docker-deployer only
    <Limit POST PUT DELETE PATCH>
        AuthName "Registry Authentication"
        AuthType basic
        AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.htpasswd"
        AuthGroupFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.groups"
        Require group pusher
    </Limit>

</Location>
```

I didn't test, just to give you an idea.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I'm able to `pull`; however, `push` fails with `unauthorized user` despite being logged in.

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/azurecr-test/distribution-westus2/blob/cce01b37ed48691347d2ab1f66b0550c486f9b0f/contrib/apache/apache.conf

Comment: Are you part of the group pusher? Maybe you need to also add Require valid-user?

Comment: Hi @SergioSantiago. Yes, of course I'm part of group pusher when logged in.

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani. That's identical to the Docker-provided example, and it doesn't answer my question.